# Google Charts API documentation?

Tags: java, android, charts

I'm trying to use the Google Chart API. I am only trying to build a String link to load in a webview. Where do I get the Documentation on which labels are available?

```
cht= Type,
chs=  Size
```

etc...

Is there a full documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's now under the visualization API.

Is this what you're looking for by any chance?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts

Be keep in mind that **it's deprecated now**.